# Suggestion on speeding up XGBoost Fitting in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I have a i7 16GB Mac and I want to apply a CV grid search on XGBoost. The dataset is quite large in the shape of 13 mil by 50 cols. Here's my code:

```
cv_params = {'max_depth': [3], 'min_child_weight': [1]}
ind_params = {'learning_rate': 0.1, 'n_estimators': 1000, 'seed': 0, 'subsample': 0.8, 'colsample_bytree': 0.8,
             'objective': 'binary:logistic'}
optimized_GBM = GridSearchCV(xgb.XGBClassifier(**ind_params),
                            cv_params,
                            scoring = 'accuracy', cv = 5, n_jobs = -1)

train_features = train.drop('reordered', axis=1)
train_y = train['reordered']

optimized_GBM.fit(train_features, train_y)
```

Computationally, is there any way to boost the speed on fitting the data? I've been waiting hours. It appears that if I try multiple levels of cv_params, the fitting might take days which I don't have. Besides reducing dimensions or deploying this on AWS instance, is there any quick solution on giving this a speed boost?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about reducing number of estimators for starter? 1000 is a lot. What's the size of your data? Can you confirm that all (virtual) cores are busy? On i7 you should expect 8 jobs running and taking ~100% cpu.

Comment: Last time I checked it was maxing out CPU usage. You are right 1k estimators is probably more than what I need. Is there a rough guideline on how many estimators are generally good enough for the model to perform well?

Comment: Start with a smaller sample, get a sense which way the best parameter values move as you increase the sample size, project your hunch towards the full size sample... Also check your memory use: this dataset alone is ~2.5G in float32 format, and you are running parallel CV, which is probably creating some copies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GPU, you can add the parameter to the model as: `tree_method='gpu_hist'`.

Also, without reducing n_estimators, you can add two parameters to:

```
optimized_GBM.fit(train_features, train_y, 
                   eval_set=[(train_features,train_y),(test_features,test_y)],
                   early_stopping_rounds=5)
```

where 5 means no improvements in the last 5 consecutive steps; you can set for train_features any value you want. So, if there are no improvements, the fitting will stop and not all n-estimators will be consumed. Unfortunately, as I am aware, this does not work with GridsearchCV.